# How to make custom HTML block floatable/scrollable in Moodle

Tags: html, css, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.91.

I am trying to make certain custom HTML blocks on the side of a course in Moodle, floatable, so they move with you when you scroll down a page. I would like to do it only for certain HTML blocks, is it possible?

If so, can you please guide me what changes should I be making and in where?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Pooja

Comment: I think the first thing we'd need to know to help on this would be something about the theme you're using.  If it's an existing theme, which one is it?  Which blocks are you trying to "float" - you say HTML blocks, but will all "HTML" blocks float, or just some of them?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the response. The theme being used in More, one of the default themes and I need to float the custom HTML block but on on certain course pages.Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Did you try giving that block some `id, class` and work on `floating, scrolling` in `css/javascript' ?

Comment: @AshrafHefny I think that would not be possible to specify inside tht HTML block, as it's the surrounding divs that will need to be floated rather than the ones inside the HTML block content area itself.  Ultimately, you need a way that can identify which page you're on, and which block (of potentially many HTML blocks) you're floating.  That way you can create the CSS to target it.

I think the most correct way would be to use custom renderers, but I've not the experience to really offer any guidance there.

Comment: Thanks Ashraf and Martin! Yes, Martin you're right, that's exactly what I meant. I also posted this on Moodle forums and somebody provided me a JS snippet and css line of code but unfortunately I am not sure where can I add it. Once i get the response and am able to get it working will post the solution here. https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=342168#p1379612 - Forum link

Answer (score 0):

Moodle 2.6:

Need to make the question grid (on the top leftmost corner of a page) as floating so that the same scrolls up-down as and when the page is scrolled. Presently if each page contains options/questions more than 5, the question grid gets lost once you scroll down the page. This creates an issue with non-conversant participants.